# Javascript to create multiple div elements onclick

Tags: javascript, css, positioning

I need help with this app. I want the user to choose a name, color and number. When the form is submitted, boxes of the chosen color and number are generated. More boxes can be added and the originals are not erased. Each box has random positioning and a unique id.
Here is my effort: http://jsfiddle.net/christopherpl/gnVj6/

```
//Invoke functions only after page has fully loaded
window.onload = init;

//Create an array that will be populated by the user generated boxes
var boxes = [];

//Create a global counter variable that keeps track of the number of 
//boxes generated
var counter = 0;

//Create a Box constructor function with parameters, to create box objects
//for each box that's generated
function Box(id, name, color, x, y) {
this.id = id;
this.name = name;
this.color = color;
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
}

//Set up the onclick event handler for the generate button input
function init() {
var generateButton = document.getElementById("generateButton");
generateButton.onclick = generate;

var clearButton = document.getElementById("clearButton");
clearButton.onclick = clear;
}

//Get boxes' name from user
function generate() {
var data = document.forms.data;
var textInput = document.getElementById("name");
var name = textInput.value;
if (name == null || name == "") {
alert("Please give your Amazing Box a name");
return;
}

//Get color option from user
var colorSelect = document.getElementById("color");
var colorOption = colorSelect.options[colorSelect.selectedIndex];
var color = colorOption.value;
if (!color) {
alert("Pick a color");
return;
}

//Get number of boxes to be generated from user 
var amountArray = data.elements.amount;
for (i = 0; i < amountArray.length; i++) {
if (amountArray[i].checked) {

//Create and append the new <div> element
var div = document.createElement("div");

//Randomly position each <div> element
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (scene.offsetWidth-101));
var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (scene.offsetHeight-101));

//Give each <div> element a unique id
var newId = div;
newId = counter++;
id = newId;

//Add the style, including the background color selected
//by the user.
div.style.left = x + "px";
div.style.top = y + "px";
div.style.backgroundColor = color;    
div.setAttribute("class", "box");

scene.appendChild(div);
div.innerHTML = "Box of " + name + "<br />(click me)";

//Create an onclick event displaying the 
//details of each box generated
div.onclick = function() {
alert("You clicked on a box with id " + id + 
", named Box of " + name + ", whose color is " + color + 
" at position " + div.style.top + ", " + div.style.left)
}

//Form reset
data = document.getElementById("data");
data.reset();
}
}
}

//Clear the boxes from scene div            
function clear() {
var sceneDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div#scene div");
for (var i = 0; i < sceneDivs.length; i++) {
var scene = document.getElementById("scene");
var cutList = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1];
scene.removeChild(cutList);
}
}
```

Comment: What is your actual question? We can't just write your code for you!

Comment: beegle bug, please take a look at the link under my description. I can't generate the multiple boxes -  Thanks

Comment: I still see no question, sorry! Is there a particular area you want help with? A line of code that is not working, a concept you are having difficulty with?

Comment: Hi beeglebug I am pretty sure my problem is here //Get number of boxes to be generated from user 
var amountArray = data.elements.amount;
for (i = 0; i < amountArray.length; i++) {
if (amountArray[i].checked) {

//Create and append the new <div> element
var div = document.createElement("div");

Comment: I can't get the multiple boxes (ie what the user chooses) to be generated

Comment: Well, I've only had a quick look but it seems that you're not passing any arguments to any of the functions that you're trying to run. But I could, easily enough, be misunderstanding something.

Comment: Thanks David, I will take a look at that and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, when you do this loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < amountArray.length; i++) {
    if (amountArray[i].checked) {
        /* make the div */
    }
}
```

You are always just making one box. What you need to do is a second loop, using the value of the radio button as the length of the loop. Something like:

```
var totalBoxes = 0;
for (i = 0; i < amountArray.length; i++) {
    if (amountArray[i].checked) {
        totalBoxes = amountArray[i].value;
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < totalBoxes; i++) {
    /* make the div */
}
```

That way you will get 5 boxes if the user checked the 5 box, and so on.